# How can I prevent a process waiting for a specific write from being pending

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i have the following simple write to `database real time`

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('A').update({
    'name': 'my name',
});
```

I noticed if I did this writing process in case there is no connection, it will wait the
connection to be available again then it will write .. but How can i prevent it

in other word How can i make this process write only be Successful if user has connection to
the internet and ignore any pending process write even if they were writing in offline mode

i need it for only specific method and not all

Comment: Please specify the system and language you want

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fire the write event when you have an internet connection, you can achieve this is by checking your internet connection before you call the function using internet_connection_checker package https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

bool hasConnection = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;

if (hasConnection) {
  // This will only fire if you are connected to the internet
  FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('A').update({
    'name': 'my name',
  });
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you are using firebase realtime database, you can use the `.info/connected` reference to determine if you are connected or not https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

```
var bool hasConnection = false;

final connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  hasConnection = event.snapshot.value as bool? ?? false;
});

if (hasConnection) {
  // This will only fire if you are connected to the internet
  FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('A').update({
    'name': 'my name',
  });
}
```

Comment: not in case if there was connection but no internet access !

Comment: Can you give an example of when this wouldn't work?

Comment: @Jack I just updated the answer so that it actually checks if it's connected to firebase database first

Answer (score -2):

You can easily wrap this in a Future.value like this :

```
var future = Future.value(FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('A').update({'name': 'my name',}););
future.then((value) => print(value));
```

One can imagine that you will setState in the then which will update the UI.

Comment: No , it is still write